# condition in the stored procedure for the search of date is not functioning

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a stored procedure which filters the records of license application by status, ship name and expiry date. The code had run for the filtering of the status and ship name except for the `EXPIRY DATE`.

The function should filter the expiry date based on the input on the textbox using ajax calendar.

I think there's something wrong with my condition for the filtering of the expiry date.

Any suggestions ?

```
USE [PhilfishPhilcatch]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[rectesting]    Script Date: 11/07/2013 08:53:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rectesting]


@VesselName Varchar (30) = NULL,
@Status Varchar (10) = NULL,
@DateReleased date = NULL,
@ExpiryDate date = NULL,
@DateIssued date = NULL,
@Cfvgl_Upload varchar = NULL


AS
    BEGIN
        IF (@Status = 1)
            begin
            SELECT a.v_id, a.ship_name, b.status, b.cfvgl_validity_start , b.cfvgl_validity_end, b.cfvgl_path, b.cfvgl_date_released 
            FROM vessel_details as a INNER JOIN
            cfvgl as b ON a.v_id = b.v_id 
            WHERE
            a.ship_name LIKE ISNULL(@VesselName+'%', a.ship_name) AND
            (b.status = 4 OR b.status = 7)  
            end 

        IF (@Status <> NULL OR @Status <> '')
        begin
            SELECT a.v_id, a.ship_name, b.status, b.cfvgl_validity_start , b.cfvgl_validity_end, b.cfvgl_path, b.cfvgl_date_released 
            FROM vessel_details as a INNER JOIN
            cfvgl as b ON a.v_id = b.v_id 
            WHERE
            a.ship_name LIKE ISNULL(@VesselName+'%', a.ship_name) AND
            b.status = @Status  
            end

        IF (@ExpiryDate <> NULL OR @ExpiryDate <> '')
        begin   
            SELECT a.v_id, a.ship_name, b.status, b.cfvgl_validity_start , b.cfvgl_validity_end, b.cfvgl_path, b.cfvgl_date_released 
            FROM vessel_details as a INNER JOIN
            cfvgl as b ON a.v_id = b.v_id 
            WHERE
            b.cfvgl_validity_end = ISNULL (@ExpiryDate, b.cfvgl_validity_end)
        end
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Status <> NULL
```

should be

```
@Status IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a value is NULL or not, you cannot explicitly compare to NULL. You need to write the statement as:

```
IF (@EXPIRY_DATE IS NOT NULL OR ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
IF ( NULLIF( @ExpiryDate, '' ) IS NOT NULL )
...
```

Comment: my condition is to check if the expiry date is not null , it will search the record that will match the input on the textbox .. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Null value can not comparison with (= > <) operators.
Use 'IS' operator for this Case